# Issue with masked input plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use masked input to make my date look like 9999-99-99 but doesen't seem to be effecting anything. I can't tell what I am doing wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://digitalbush.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.1.min_.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function ($) {
$("#date").mask("9999-99-99");
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/doitlikejustin/xw2je/3/

This is my input box-

```
<input name="date" type="text" id="date" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['date'];?>" />
```

Comment: Are you using a correct link for the javascript file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include jQuery script first.

The order is important, since jQuery Masked input plugin depends on jQuery. You should tell the browser to load jQuery first and then only you can work on jQuery stuff.

For example (I tested this):

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://digitalbush.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.1.min_.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#date").mask("9999-99-99");
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input name="date" type="text" id="date" value="" />
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Right, I thought I was? I used your code, did not seem to work. Could this be a problem? 'code' <input name="date" type="text" id="date" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['date'];?>" />

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem. May be you have some errors in the page. You can use Firebug on Firefox to see whether there are JavaScript errors

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change jquery definition order, put version jquery file first and then put plugin jquery. It will solve your problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://digitalbush.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.1.min_.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

main jquery file should place first and then the addon.It will definitely solve ur problem.